# Combine toHaveBeenCalledTimes with toBeGreaterThan

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular2-testing

Is there a way in `jasmine` where I can combine `toHaveBeenCalledTimes` with `toBeGreaterThan`?

I want to know whether the spy object has called a particular method at least 2 times.

spy Object

```
spyOn(component.videos, 'update').and.callThrough();
```

I know we can verify it for exact number of times, but in my case `update` method can be called any number of times. I want to check if it has been called at least twice

something like below expect statement

```
expect(component.videos.update).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2).toBeGreaterThan(2);
```

I know it is a wrong syntax, but is there anything similar to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different assertions that aren't supposed to be chained.

It likely should be:

```
expect(component.videos.update.calls.count()).not.toBeLessThan(2);
```